# NYC estate tax for foreigners

Tags: real-estate

We are a married male couple (with kids) and we bought an apartment in NYC for investment (the apartment is not ready yet). Note that we do not have US citizenship and we don't live in the US. We were told that if one of us dies we would have to pay Estate tax. Assuming the apartment costs 1 million dollars, how much estate tax will we pay? When will we have to pay the tax(when we sell the apartment later on?)
Thanks

Comment: This might be a better fit for [Money.SE].